# Balana: Root policy with issuer is treated like a trusted policy

Tags: wso2, xacml3

I implemented the [wso2 Balana PDP](https://github.com/wso2/balana).
I have a simple policy issued by Bob giving subject Alice permission. When I evaluate a request from Alice the implementation returns a Permit even though there is no trusted policy (I assumed it should return NotApplicable).

As far as I understand there needs to be at least one policy without issuer as the root of the reduction graph ([OASIS Specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-administration-v1-spec-cd-1-en.html#_Toc230521661)).

Do I need to implement the policy finder differently or did I misunderstand the administration concept?

This is the PDP code:

```
package xacmlimplementation.wso2;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.wso2.balana.Balana;
import org.wso2.balana.PDP;
import org.wso2.balana.PDPConfig;
import org.wso2.balana.ParsingException;
import org.wso2.balana.combine.PolicyCombiningAlgorithm;
import org.wso2.balana.combine.xacml2.FirstApplicablePolicyAlg;
import org.wso2.balana.ctx.AbstractResult;
import org.wso2.balana.ctx.ResponseCtx;
import org.wso2.balana.finder.AttributeFinderModule;
import org.wso2.balana.finder.PolicyFinder;
import org.wso2.balana.finder.PolicyFinderModule;
import org.wso2.balana.finder.impl.FileBasedPolicyFinderModule;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import xacmlimplementation.engine.XacmlResult;
import xacmlimplementation.engine.XacmlResult.Decision;
import xacmlimplementation.engine.XacmlResult.ErrorType;

public class TestBalana {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> policyLocations = new HashSet<String>();
        policyLocations.add("/path/to/policy.xml");
        String request = "/path/to/request.xml";

        // create default instance of Balana
        Balana balana = Balana.getInstance();

        // Default PDP config
        PDPConfig pdpConfig = balana.getPdpConfig();

        // Set up policy finder
        PolicyCombiningAlgorithm wso2Alg = new FirstApplicablePolicyAlg();

        PolicyFinder policyFinder = new PolicyFinder();
        Set<PolicyFinderModule> policyFinderModules = new HashSet<PolicyFinderModule>();

        // module for the root policies
        // FileBasedPolicyFinderModule uses DenyOverrides
        PolicyFinderModule policyModule = new FileBasedPolicyFinderModule(policyLocations);
        policyFinderModules.add(policyModule);

        policyFinder.setModules(policyFinderModules);

        PDP pdp = new PDP(new PDPConfig(pdpConfig.getAttributeFinder(), policyFinder, null));

        String requestString = null;
        try {
            Path p = Paths.get(request);
            byte[] content = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(p);
            requestString = new String(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading "+request);
            return;
        }

        String response = pdp.evaluate(requestString);

        ResponseCtx responseCtx = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = null;
        AbstractResult result = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
            Document doc;

            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
            dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

            doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);
            responseCtx = ResponseCtx.getInstance(doc.getDocumentElement());

            Iterator<AbstractResult> it = responseCtx.getResults().iterator();
            result = it.next();
        } catch (ParsingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error parsing xacml response: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Result list is empty");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           System.err.println("Error in closing input stream of XACML response");
           return;
        }

        //System.out.println(result.encode());

        switch (result.getDecision()) {
        case AbstractResult.DECISION_PERMIT:
            System.out.println("Permit");
            break;

        case AbstractResult.DECISION_DENY:
            System.out.println("Deny");
            break;

        case AbstractResult.DECISION_NOT_APPLICABLE:
            System.out.println("NotApplicable");
            break;

        case AbstractResult.DECISION_INDETERMINATE:
        case AbstractResult.DECISION_INDETERMINATE_PERMIT:
        case AbstractResult.DECISION_INDETERMINATE_DENY:
        case AbstractResult.DECISION_INDETERMINATE_DENY_OR_PERMIT:
            System.out.println("Indeterminate");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Decision doesn't match Permit, Deny, NotApplicable, ...");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<PolicySet xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:policy-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" PolicySetId="PolicySet1" Version="1.0">
  <Target/>

  <Policy PolicyId="PolicyBobGrantsAliceAccess" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" Version="1.0">
    <PolicyIssuer>
      <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="true">
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Bob</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
    </PolicyIssuer>
    <Target>
      <AnyOf>
        <AllOf>
          <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Alice</AttributeValue>
        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
          </Match>
        </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
    </Target>
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule1">
      <Target/>
    </Rule>
  </Policy>
</PolicySet>
```

The request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
  <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Alice</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
</Request>
```